# Take string output from command, and search for that string in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

I am wondering how to use the output from a command as the pattern argument of `grep`? In particular, I have this command I've cooked up (with help from another question):

```
grep PATTERN file.txt | awk 'NR == 1 {line = $0; min = $5} NR > 1 && $5 < min {line = $0; min = $5} END{print $5}'
```

that will search file.txt for the line whose 5th column has the lowest value, then print that value. However, I want to then redirect that into `grep` again, to search file.txt again for that line, so that I may print at least 2 lines above, and 5 lines below (though more isnt' a big deal).

I've looked around, and I know that piping output into `grep` means you search that output for the argument you give to `grep` - but I am not sure how to do it the other way around?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure highlight the code you post, so others can clearly see it and understand it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the output of the command as a command line argment to grep, you can use a subshell with `$( ...)` syntax.

```
grep $(grep PATTERN file.txt | awk 'NR == 1 {line = $0; min = $5} NR > 1 && $5 < min {line = $0; min = $5} END{print $5}') Haystack
```

To get 2 lines of context above and 5 lines below, you can use the `-A` and `-B` flags.

```
grep -B2 -A5 $(grep PATTERN file.txt | awk 'NR == 1 {line = $0; min = $5} NR > 1 && $5 < min {line = $0; min = $5} END{print $5}') Haystack
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out. I can redirect the output to a file, then grep using the -f option to search for the strings in that file. Thanks anyway! Hope this helps if you are reading this with the same problem as me...

Answer (score 0):

Why not do all in one `awk`

```
awk '/PATTERN/ && (!min || $5 < min) {min=$5;c=NR} {a[NR]=$0} END{for (i=c-2;i<=c+5;i++) print a[i]}' file
```

This find the line number where filed `5` has lowest value and store it in `c`
It also store all lines in array `a` with line number as index.
Then in end section it prints out from array `a` 2 lines before and `5` lines after, including the hit line.